# Fail to install elasticsearch-8.2.0 on Ubuntu machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I downloaded the `.tar.gz` file on a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS machine, and `shasum` output OK. After unzipping the file and running `./bin/elasticsearch`, the following error happens:

```
[0.001s][warning][os,container] Duplicate cpuset controllers detected. Picking /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset, skipping /run/lxcfs/controllers/cpuset.
Error: Could not find or load main class [0.001s][warning][os,container]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [0/001s][warning][os,container]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

[Elasticsearch 8.2](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix) does not seems to support (officially) `Ubuntu 16.04`.

## To Solve

Maybe you can look into [Elasticsearch on docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) ?

Or upgrade to a newer version of `Ubuntu` ?

Comment: Same issue for elasticsearch 7.17.3, which is reported to support Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you running the `.bat` file ? Or the `.msi` ?

Comment: I'm running the bash script on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.